# Boost filtering_stream and tellp

Tags: c++, boost, boost-iostreams

I'm trying to using filtering_streams to compress the serialization of some object into an `array_sink` or similar device where I can then determine the length of the compressed output and copy it to another stream, say a file.  However, using `ostream::tellp` on the `filtering_ostream` causes boost to throw a runtime exception.  I can't really figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
using namespace boost::iostreams;

char *buffer = new char[4096*255];
array_sink zipStream(buffer, 4096*255);

filtering_ostream tempOut;
tempOut.push(zlib_compressor());
tempOut.push(zipStream);

column->Serialize(tempOut); // Object::Serialize(ostream&)
tempOut.flush(); // ?
int zipSize = tempOut.tellp();

// Do stuff with zipStream...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `tellp` is implemented in terms of the underlying stream buffers `pubseekoff` with 0 offset from current write head position ( basically, it's just poor design ). Now, the kicker here is that `zlib_compressor` does not work with `output_seekable` sinks ( as can be seen in the docs ). This is fairly natural since changing the write head would almost definitively lead to corrupted data. You have the very same problem if you try to decompress.

Comment: Thanks!  I was working along this line of thought too, though it didn't occur to me that not being seekable would prevent tellp--however, running through the stack I saw it was indeed trying to seek and that that was throwing the exception.  I've achieved what I want by putting a `counter` filter in the stream.